# Android ANR error

Tags: android

I am using android service by calling startService(), and at the same time, I bind the service to activity to communicate with it through messengers.

I got this error when I quit the app after playing around.

I checked the /data/anr/traces.txt, it like this:

```
   "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
10   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40fae508 self=0x40f67b78
11   | sysTid=11746 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074597680
12   | schedstat=( 2272796932 1135546599 7858 ) utm=175 stm=51 core=3
13   #00  pc 0000da70  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
14   #01  pc 00014899  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
15   #02  pc 00014b01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
16   #03  pc 00063653  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
17   #04  pc 0001deb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
18   #05  pc 0004d103  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
19   #06  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
20   #07  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
21   #08  pc 0005fb37  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
22   #09  pc 000670e5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
23   #10  pc 000272e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
24   #11  pc 0002bbe8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
25   #12  pc 0005f871  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
26   #13  pc 000496f3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
27   #14  pc 0004c571  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
28   #15  pc 0004d6d3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
29   #16  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
30   #17  pc 00017123  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
31   #18  pc 00000b34  /system/bin/app_process
32   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
33   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
34   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
35   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
36   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
37   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
38   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
39   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
40   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Dunno if this solves your problem, but you rarely need to call **startService()** and **bind()** on the same service. Either one will start the service.

Comment: @EdwardFalk startService() because I need the service running all the time even though the activity is destroyed, bind() because I need activity communicate with the service.

Comment: You can achieve this without binding as well. Binding service has different purpose not to communicate with activity

Comment: Really? I thought that was the primary reason for binding -- to establish a 2-way link with the service.

Comment: onBind automatically start service. Please show your code

Comment: @BrijeshThakur Thanks, I've removed the bindService(), communicate by messenger instead. thanks !